# Merging columns into float type

Tags: python, pandas

Given Data Frame df =

```
ordinal     id          A           B
 1          14318       45.0714     7.6187
 2          14318       45.0739     7.6195
 3          14318       45.0745     7.6152
 4          14318       45.0833     7.6145
 5          14318       45.0946     7.6194
```

I want to merge columns A and B into column C by unique values of 'id'. So, I have tried the following code:

```
df['C'] = list(zip(df.A.astype(float), df.B.astype(float)))
```

Here **type** of column C is object. But I need float or int. I mean, I need something like

```
([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],  [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
```

but I get:

```
ordinal id      A           B       C
    1   14318   45.0714     7.6187  (45.0714, 7.6187)
    2   14318   45.0739     7.6195  (45.0739, 7.6195)
    3   14318   45.0745     7.6152  (45.0745, 7.6152)
    4   14318   45.0833     7.6145  (45.0833, 7.6145)
```

EDITED

Desired output:

```
id      C
14318   ([[45.0714, 7.6187], [45.0739, 7.6195], [45.0745, 7.6152],  [45.0833, 7.6145]])
```

Comment: how do you want to save two numbers in one cell? this has to be type object

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data? Maybe is necessary change input sample for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A `tuple` or an array of two elements can never be type `float` or `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC need:

```
df['C'] = list(zip(df.A.astype(int), df.B.astype(int)))

print (df)
   ordinal     id        A       B        C
0        1  14318  45.0714  7.6187  (45, 7)
1        2  14318  45.0739  7.6195  (45, 7)
2        3  14318  45.0745  7.6152  (45, 7)
3        4  14318  45.0833  7.6145  (45, 7)
4        5  14318  45.0946  7.6194  (45, 7)
```

If need lists:

```
df['C'] = [list(x) for x in zip(df.A.astype(float), df.B.astype(float))]
#alternative
#df['C'] = list(map(list, zip(df.A.astype(float), df.B.astype(float))))

print (df)
   ordinal     id        A       B                  C
0        1  14318  45.0714  7.6187  [45.0714, 7.6187]
1        2  14318  45.0739  7.6195  [45.0739, 7.6195]
2        3  14318  45.0745  7.6152  [45.0745, 7.6152]
3        4  14318  45.0833  7.6145  [45.0833, 7.6145]
4        5  14318  45.0946  7.6194  [45.0946, 7.6194]
```

Comment: I did it as well, but in this case I lose the precision. These numbers show the coordinates

Comment: @Mamed - yes, but then it is expected - if use integer, precision is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` method:

```
df[['A', 'B']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
0    (45.0714, 7.6187)
1    (45.0739, 7.6195)
2    (45.0745, 7.6152)
3    (45.0833, 7.6145)
4    (45.0946, 7.6194)
```

or, to get a tuple of ints:

```
df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: tuple(map(int, x)), axis=1)
```

However, the new object type will be `object` not `float` or `int` since it is an array.